# Inherit instance variable from parent class

Tags: python-3.x, class

main.py

```
   ...
   person = cPerson("xyz", "ozp")
   ...
   person.set_name("somename")
   ...
   csystem = cSystem()
   ...
```

cperson.py

```
   class cPerson:
      def __init__(self, addr, client):
         self.addr = addr
         self.client = client
         self.name = None

      def set_name(self, name):
         self.name = name
```

csystem.py

```
   from cperson import cPerson

      class cSystem(cPerson):
         def __init__(self):
            print(self.name)
```

Can i access self.name from the parent class in this way? I get the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'cSystem' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I do not want to initialize from the csystem class, i want the current value from the instance variable set as shown in the main program.

Comment: You could use the super().__init__(name) to inherit the name attribute from cPerson

Comment: When edited accordingly i get the following error: NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Comment: Is it even possible what i am trying to do? I mean: initialising class cPerson and accessing its instance variables from cSystem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you want the end result to be.

In any case is this what you are looking for?

```
class cPerson:

    name = None

    def __init__(self, addr, client):
        self.addr = addr
        self.client = client

    @classmethod
    def set_name(cls, value):
        cls.name = value


class cSystem(cPerson):
    def __init__(self, addr, client):
        super().__init__(addr, client)
        print(self.name)


person = cPerson("xyz", "ozp")
person.set_name('Jake')

csystem = cSystem("xyz", "ozp")
```

The above code returns 'Jake'.

A class method is a method which is bound to the class and not the object of the class. They have the access to the state of the class as it takes a class parameter that points to the class and not the object instance.

Is this what you were looking for? If not can you explain the problem in a bit more detail?